# Site transferred to new server produces 404s

Tags: urls, slug, hosting

I have transferred my site to a new server. I can login to wp-admin ok and can view the home page but all other pages produce 404s.

I have changed the 'Home' and 'Site URL' options in the settings area but this makes no difference.

Does anyone know how to amend this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you repub'd your permalinks? This will update the .htaccess file to ensure that routing works appropriately.